# Dynamically loaded javascript executed twice

Tags: javascript

OK, I've got a nasty situation where everything works fine in my custom written script loader except the fact the script being loaded is **executed twice**.

here is complete code:

```
window._appCommons=window._appCommons||{};
$.loadScr = function(path, name, exportParam){
  var df = $.Deferred();
  if (! $( ['script[data-mname="', name, '"]'].join('') ).length ) {
    window._appCommons[name] = {};
    this.get(path).done(function(data){
        for (var prop in exportParam) {
            window._appCommons[name][prop] = exportParam[prop];
        }
        var scr = ['<script data-mname="' , name , '">' , data, '<\/script>'].join('');
        $(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]).append( scr );
        setTimeout(function(){ df.resolve(); },16);
    });
  }
  return df;
}

$.loadScr('one.js', 'onejs', {'someKey':'someValue'}).done(function(){});
```

The loaded script - `one.js` only contain `console.log('something...')` statement and I get this **twice**.

### I can confirm:

- that script appending - `.append( scr );` happened only once
- that script is "physically" loaded only once (confirmed from network
  panel)

and still, the same `one.js`, loaded once, appended once is executed twice.

So, does anyone have an idea what's happening?

### UPDATE

I can now confirm that script is executed *immediately after ajax loading*, no matter of being appended or not. That means pure loading of javascript file, simple like `$.get('one.js')` **executes containing javascript code**. I do not know if this should happen and is there workaround or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sake of completeness I have to respond to my own question - it's `jQuery.get()` default settings to blame - there is `dataType` field, which, if not set explicitly, becomes subject to what's called `Intelligent Guess` - and in case of loading script `jQuery` actually bothers to recognize javascript code and execute it.

My problem was solved by changing `this.get(path).done...` to:

```
    this.ajax({
      url: path,
      dataType: 'text'
    })
    .done//...
```

which doesn't execute received code, as it should be at first place.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using this? Personally tested and used script:

```
function loadjscssfile (filename, filetype){
    if (filetype=="js") { //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    else if (filetype=="css") { //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js") //dynamically load and add this .js file
loadjscssfile("javascript.php", "js") //dynamically load "javascript.php" as a JavaScript file
loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css") ////dynamically load and add this .css file
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen, I'll check it out, but I have to fix this.

Comment: it works and the script executes once

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `jQuery.append` to native `Node.appendChild` fixed the issue in my case

```
document.head.appendChild(scriptEl);
```